# Is this group by size behavior correct?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this sample dataset:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'city':['Porto','Loa','Porto','Porto','Loa'],\
                     'town':['A','C','A','B','C']})
mydf['city'] = pd.Categorical(mydf['city'])
mydf['town'] = pd.Categorical(mydf['town'])
mydf
    city    town
0   Porto   A
1   Loa     C
2   Porto   A
3   Porto   B
4   Loa     C
```

And I want to count the occurrences grouped by city and town. So I tried this:

```
mydf.groupby(['city','town']).size().to_frame()
              0
city    town    
Loa     A     0
        B     0
        C     2
Porto   A     2
        B     1
        C     0
```

But this is wrong, since city C is located only in Loa, not in Porto, and cities A and B are located only in Porto. My expected result is this:

```
              0
city    town    
Loa     C     2
Porto   A     2
        B     1
```

Sure I can avoid the `pd.Categorical` conversion in 'city' and 'town', but I don't understand that behavior. Is there a parameter I should use to avoid this and get the right and simplified expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, the `groupby` + `size` behavior is expected.**

By default, if any of the grouping columns are categorical then it will show all the values for categorical columns regardless whether they appear in a particular group or not.

To turn this default behaviors off, you can set the optional parameter `observed=True` in `groupby` which will show only observed values(actual appearing values) of categorical columns:

```
mydf.groupby(['city','town'], observed=True).size().to_frame()
```

---

```
            0
city  town   
Porto A     2
      B     1
Loa   C     2
```

Comment: I was so troubled with this and now the parameter you provide solves my problem! I  Thank you very much!, Have a great dat!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from collections import Counter
mydf.groupby(['city'], observed=True)['town'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x))
```

Output:

```
city    
Porto  A    2.0
       B    1.0
Loa    C    2.0
Name: town, dtype: float64
```